# Python operators pymysql

Tags: python, mysql, operators, pymysql

I'm having some bad time with pymysql and python operators.
I don't know much about python operator though.

I want to insert into the database some values. The code:

```
import pymysql
conn = pymysql.connect(host='127.0.0.1', unix_socket='/Applications/MAMP/tmp/mysql/mysql.sock', user='root', passwd='root', db='db2', charset='utf8')
cur = conn.cursor()
v = (123 , 'foobarfoobar', 'foo', 1241, 3, 132 )
cur.execute("INSERT INTO celebs(num_id, Text, Handle, Followers, RT, Timestamp) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", v)
```

For the record mySQL structure is `INT (PRI), INT, TEXT, VARCHAR, INT, INT, VARCHAR`.

I run this and I get `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`

Any details how to solve it and possibly some explanation how operator work in python.
In php is easier I think: `$a = 22; echo "$a days";`

Update:

I'm using directly the Insert into and it still doesn't insert the data:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO celebs (num_id, Text, Handle, Followers, RT, Timestamp) VALUES (123 , 'foobarfoobar', 'foo', 1241, 3, 132 );"  )
```

Comment: v = ('123' , 'foobarfoobar', 'foo', '1241', '3', '132' )
Add quotes around the numbers will make them strings and should avoid your problem. 
http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/petehunt/PyMySQL/blob/master/pymysql/__init__.py#L49), the [`paramstyle`](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#paramstyle) is `format`, so you'll need to change...

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?)", v)
```

...to...

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO ... VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", v)
```

If you're using a transactional storage engine such as InnoDB, you'll have to explicitly commit the transaction by calling `conn.commit()` after doing the `INSERT` query.

Comment: Unfortunately I tried this as well and didn't work. `SELECT` though works smoothly. Additionally if I run the query straight to mySQL with the `v`'s values they are inserted correctly... I think pymysql isn't working correctly. I'm trying to install other connectors now

Comment: @DDL449 In what way did it not work? Did you get the same error or something else?

Comment: there was no error in the script but it didn't insert the values to the db

Comment: @DDL449 See updated answer. I also noticed you used `INSERT INTO celebs('num_id', ...` which is invalid SQL - it should be `INSERT INTO celebs(num_id, ...`

Comment: Correct. Though tried it and still doesn't work. I updated my answer with my lastest simple query I try to insert

Comment: @DDL449 Did you not see the part I added to the answer about `conn.commit()`?

Comment: Nop. :) Thank you! That was the missing piece!

Answer (score 0):

i think the mistake is in the data structure of v . it should be list not tuple

Answer (score 0):

Check mysql engine. Pymysql is not working with InnDB but it is working fine when I changed from InnoDB to MyISAM